# epoch time format to python datetime

Tags: python, pandas, epoch

I am reading data from csv file with pandas. The time column is in epoch format which needs to be converted to human readable datetime. The dataframe looks like this:

```
name    time    rCurrentL1  rCurrentL2  rCurrentL3
0   Assembler_No1BC1_ElecData   1623691319004000000 0.0032874299213290215   0.0021221311762928963   0.00042045069858431816
1   Assembler_No1BC1_ElecData   1623691319005000000 0.0032874299213290215   0.0021221311762928963   0.00042045069858431816
2   Assembler_No1BC1_ElecData   1623691319006000000 0.0032874299213290215   0.0021221311762928963   0.00042045069858431816
```

I tried `pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ns')` but get `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`. Could anyone help me how to fix this? Or is there a better way to convert epoch to datetime?

Comment: Yout data form me working well, what is your pandas version?

Comment: What is the output of `pd.to_datetime(df['time'] / 1000000, unit='ms')`

Comment: Check if you have a value greater than pd.Timestamp.max: `df['time'].gt(pd.Timestamp.max.value).sum()`

Comment: @jezrael  pandas version : 1.2.4

Comment: @Corralien TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'    
'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Cast to `int64` before: `df['time'].astype('int64').gt(pd.Timestamp.max.value).sum()`

Comment: @Corralien I get error invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'time'

Comment: All rows in time column do not contain numbers. Find them with `df[pd.to_numeric(df['time'], errors='coerce').isna()]` and fix.

Comment: @Corralien I plotted seaborn heatmap to check if there is any nan values before and now I just checked df.dtype and realized the data types are all objects. I think they need to be converted to numeric values first. I tried ´df['rCurrentL1'].apply(pd.to_numeric)´ Anyway, I got the error ´Unable to parse string "rCurrentL1" at position 0´.

Comment: thanks @Corralien, you're right. column names were repeated every 10000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

As @Corralien comment, some rows didn't have numeric values and could not be converted. I checked them with `df[pd.to_numeric(df['time'], errors='coerce').isna()]` and excluded them from DataFrame. Then `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ns')` worked fine.